# how to solve the swift compiler error in Xcode 9.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

As i creating my own custom framework.My framework was developed by the combination of both objective c and swift.When i changing the project location the project was not build and showing the swift compiler error but it working fine where i created.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h>//Here i am getting the error like Include of non-modular header inside framework module

//#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SpeechService.h"
```

The swift compiler error was
1)/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/SofiaPersonalAssistant 
2/SofiaPersonalAssistant/SofiapersonalassisT.framework/Headers/precomp.h:56:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'SofiapersonalassisT.precomp': '/Users/muruganandamc/Desktop/SofiaPersonalAssistant 2/SofiaPersonalAssistant/SpeechSDK.framework/Headers/SpeechRecognitionService.h'

2)Could not build Objective-C module 'SofiapersonalassisT'